# Graduate school that does not require a statement of purpose

Tags: graduate-admissions, application

I came across 3~4 graduate programs in the United States that do not require a statement of purpose, just transcript, resume, test scores & reference. What does this mean? Just want to make sure before I email the program coordinator about this. Thank you!

Comment: Presumably all it means is "this department has decided that they don't need a statement of purpose to help them make admission decisions". What else would it mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two groups of departments often do not request SoP:

- The departments, within which the diversity of the research among the corresponding faculty members are such noticeable that the applicants would be admitted to the program based on the merit, firstly. Then, they would have sufficient time to communicate with the faculty members and choose their desired research track.
- The departments, within which the interview with applicants is routine before any offer of admission. So, one might conclude that the coherency in view of the research interests with the faculty members will be investigated within the interview.